# How to return an article together with the related tags

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have three tables: Articles, Tags and ArticleTag. The Article model has a many-to-many relationship with the Tag model with the ArticleTag as their joint.
This are the models:

```
public class Article
{
    ... 

    public ICollection<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    ... 

    public ICollection<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleTag
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

This is how am getting the article:

```
public Article GetArticleById(int id)
{
    return _appContext.Articles
        .Include(a => a.ArticleTags).ThenInclude(at => at.Tag)
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

The View Model:

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    ...

    public ICollection<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var article = _unitOfWork.Articles.GetArticleById(id);

    return Ok(Mapper.Map<ArticleViewModel>(article));
}
```

The API request returns the article but the tags are not included.

Comment: Use `include`  to include `tag`

Comment: This does not seem valid: `article + article.ArticleTags.Select(at => at.Tag)`. Is there a typo here?

Comment: Is the Mapper configured to map ArticleTag to TagViewModel?

Comment: I'd imagine @AmanB is correct here. In your view model you have a collection of `TagViewModel`s, but in your entity you have you have a collection `ArticleTag`s, each with a `Tag` instance. You need to ensure that your mapping is set up correctly to map the values from each `ArticleTag` instance's `Tag` to the `TagViewModel`.

Comment: How did you configure `Mapper`? Check whether you got expected value for `var article = _unitOfWork.Articles.GetArticleById(id);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Code below to configure `Mapper`.

1. TagViewModel

   ```
   public class TagViewModel
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string TagName { get; set; }

   }
   ```
2. AutoMapperProfile

   ```
   public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
   {
      public AutoMapperProfile()
      {
         CreateMap<Article, ArticleViewModel>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ArticleTags.Select(at => at.Tag)));
         CreateMap<Tag, TagViewModel>();
      }
   }
   ```